# Add a decorator to an angularjs directive with typescript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, decorator

I created my own typescript decorator for *Component* and *Inject* and it looks like this

```
@Component(myModule, {
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  bindings: {
    value: '=',
  },
})
@Inject('service')
export class ComponentController {
  value: string;

  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
```

Where the decorators code is

```
export const Component = function(moduleOrName: string | ng.IModule, options: any): Function {
  return (controller: Function) => {
    let module = typeof moduleOrName === 'string' ? angular.module(moduleOrName) : moduleOrName;
    let component = angular.extend(options, { controller });
    module.component(options.selector, component);
  };
};

export const Inject = function(...injections: string[]): Function {
  return (target: Function) => {
    target.$inject = injections;
    return target;
  };
};
```

It works fine and now I want to do the same thing for a directive where I would need to use **compile** or **link** functions but I can't make it work

```
@Directive(app, {
  selector: 'selector',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  scope: {
    value: '=',
  },
})
@Inject('service')
export class myDirective implements ng.IDirective {
  value: string;

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  compile(element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) {
    return this.service.compile(element);
  }
}
```

The code of the **Directive** decorator is

```
export const Directive = function(moduleOrName: string | ng.IModule, options: any): Function {
  return (directive: Function) => {
    let module = typeof moduleOrName === 'string' ? angular.module(moduleOrName) : moduleOrName;
    let prueba = angular.extend(options, { directive })
    module.directive(options.selector, prueba);
  };
};
```

And when I create the directive, it always shows this error in the angular library

> Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

It could be done with a decorator or should I forget it and do it the usual way?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, `options.selector` won't work as you expect because isn't normalized. It should be noticed that controller already has got `$postLink` hook, and compile can be replaced with `template` function for inline templates.

Comment: @estus I don't get it, where should I write your code? Inside the `return (directive: Function)`?

 Also what is `new directive(...args)` doing? It shows an error.

Comment: Yes, inside. It instantiates a class. `.directive` expects factory function that will be called directly, constructors should be `new`ed. Currently TS generates JS code that allows to call class constructors which is incorrect behaviour that may change later.

Comment: I don't get all that factory thing, why is a factory needed in a directive? Should I change my directive code and include some kind of factory? 
I'm totally lost with this.

Comment: Actually, it is better to make it `let factory = (...args) => { let prueba = angular.extend(options, new directive(...args)); return prueba }; factory.$inject = directive.$inject; module.directive(options.selector, factory)`. `directive` here is a *class* of a directive object, it was you who named it `directive` in the first place. And `factory` is factory function that returns directive object. `module.directive` accepts factory function as an argument and may throw if a class constructor isn't wrapped with a factory.

Comment: Awesome!! It works with your method, but the only fault is that compile never get executed and also controller or link should work too. How can I do it?

Comment: This is caused by `angular.extend` which doesn't copy prototype props. It should be `angular.extend(new directive(...args), options)` instead. And having any props but `selector` is redundant in decorator - TS classes already have properties.

Comment: Your directive class suffers from a problem - it looks like you expect that an instance be created for each directive instance (`value` prop). This isn't true. DDO object will be created once and will be shared between all instances. You can store injected deps in `this`, but you can't store scope values there - they will be overwritten by different directive instances. A component is totally different case, `this` is a controller instance there. You may also take a look at [this](https://git.io/v6ccn) for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for all @estus, you opened my eyes. I've got the solution code working, I will paste it now and you can copy it and create a new answer to mark it as accepted and help the people that will end up here.

```@Directive(app, 'selector')
@Inject('service')
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
  templateUrl = 'template.html';
  scope = {
    value: '=',
  };

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  compile = function (element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) {
    return this.service.compile(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: Decorator:
```export const Directive = function(moduleOrName: string | ng.IModule, selector: string): Function {
  return (directive: any) => {let module = typeof moduleOrName === 'string' ? angular.module(moduleOrName) : moduleOrName;let factory = (...args: any[]) => {// Creates an empty controller for the cases that no controller is needed and controllerAs is defined
  let options = {
        controller: () => {},
      };

      return angular.extend(options, new directive(...args));
    }; factory.$inject = directive.$inject; module.directive(selector, factory);
  };
};```

Comment: Sure. In your code `controller` shouldn't be an arrow because it is a constructor. It should be also noticed that `selector` isn't a real selector, the decorator requires parsing logic to be implemented that will convert selector string to `name` and `restrict` pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
export const Directive = function(moduleOrName: string | ng.IModule, selector: string): Function {
    return (directive: any) => {
        let module = typeof moduleOrName === 'string' ? angular.module(moduleOrName) : moduleOrName;
        let factory = (...args: any[]) => {
            let options = {
                controller: function () {},
            };
            return angular.extend(new directive(...args), options);
        };
        factory.$inject = directive.$inject;
        module.directive(selector, factory);
    };
};

@Directive(app, 'selector')
@Inject('service')
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    templateUrl = 'template.html';
    scope = {
        value: '=',
    };
    constructor(private service: Service) {}
    compile = function(element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) {
        return this.service.compile(element);
    }
}
```